# How to pause a for loop, then restart in the same position?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a `for loop` which numbers and colors a set of labels (connected component labeling algorithm) inside a button click handler, how to make the loop pause after doing any step and replay in the same place in the loop after the button is clicked again?
below is the code I have:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < 161; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            if (i == 1 && labelss[i].Text == "")
            {
                labelss[i].Text = "1";
            }

            if (labelss[i].Text == "0")
            {
                //do nothing
            }
            else //if the label is not 0
            {                       
                if (labelss[i - 1].Text !="0")
                {
                    labelss[i].Text = labelss[i-1].Text;
                }
                else //if (labelss[i-1].Text=="0")
                {                            
                     if (i > 20)
                    {
                        if (labelss[i - 20].Text != "0")
                        {
                            labelss[i].Text = labelss[i - 20].Text;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            counter++;
                            labelss[i].Text = counter.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    else if(i < 20)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        labelss[i].Text = counter.ToString();                               
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HINTS: Global Boolean variable, variable to hold position, while loop/condition to check Boolean variable....

Comment: On a side not `if this... do nothing` Does that really need to be in the code still? Just inverse the if statement i.e. `if (labelss[i].Text != "0")`

Comment: Also when do you want the loop to pause, on what condition...

Comment: Is this Forms? WPF? ASPX?  The more information you provide the better answers you'll get.

Comment: Dear @TheLethalCoder thanks for the "if" tip, you are right it was useless there. I fixed the loop by taking a part from Moo's answer, thank you :)

Comment: it is a windows form @MichaelMcGriff, i fixed it, thank you dude :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is abstract your algorithm out in to a separate class independent of the button click.  This can then maintain state (such as how many labels it changed the colour of).  You'd need to pass in something like an `Func<int, bool>` which could be called each iteration and returned `true` or `false` depending on whether you wanted it to stop or not.

```
class Colourizer 
{

    private int _current;

    public void Colourize(Func<int, bool> predicate)
    {
        for(int i = _current; _current < 161; ++ _current)
        {
           // change labels here
           if(predicate(i))
               break;
        } 
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _current = 0;
    }
}

private Colourizer _colourizer = new Colourizer();
private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args) 
{
    _colourizer.Colourize((i) => false); // this just does all
}
```

Comment: Thank you dear @Moo_Juice, I didn't really check your way to see how it works for me, but I took advantage of your loop's declaration and changed mine from 'for (int i = 1; i < 161; i++)' to 'int iter=1: for (int i = iter; i < 161; i++)' and used 'break' to break the loop after each labeling and saved the position of the loop in variable "iter" before breaking. it works perfect now, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You need two things

- The for loop as a separate function, taking the "current index" as a parameter.
- A way of storing the "current index" between clicks. 
  In this example, I'm using Session.

  ```
  // Process one label only.
  public void ProcessLabel(int i)
  {
      // ... body of for loop ...
  }

  // Store current index between clicks.
  private int CurrentIndex
  {
      get { return (int)Session["MyCurrentIndex"]; }
      set { Session["MyCurrentIndex"] = value; }
  }

  // Processes one label, per click.
  private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      int i = CurrentIndex;

      if (i >= 161)
          return;     // End of for loop

      ProcessLabel(i);

      // On next click, CurrentIndex+1 will be processed.
      CurrentIndex = i + 1;
  }

  // Call this function during page initialisation.
  private void OnInit()
  {
      // Setup the first click.
      CurrentIndex = 1;
  }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

I believe using the Yield keyword will do the thing :) ..

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Comment: it doesnt solve the problem by itself, but you can show a solution where it works :)